# Disk Utility for EoS

Tags: permissions

How come I cannot find Gnome Disks for EoS?
Is there any disk utility with a GUI that I can use on EoS?
I am having problems with permissions on ext hard drives that were formatted on Mac OSX.
There is no way of changing the permissions even when logged in as Admin.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The command line utilities are: `cfdisk` and `gparted`

Also you can install Gparted:

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and the helpful instructions. My computer is now not recognising any external disc, camera, mp3 player etc at all, in any of the usb ports or with any usb cable. I doubt that I have a hardware problem but I' not sure how access any kind of system profiler on eOS. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to confirm, my usb mouse and keyboard are working fine in all/any usb port.

Answer (score 0):

Gparted is the the best option, you install the tool with

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

When you open the tool it appears to unmount all the disks and storage devices connected to the PC, so you won't see or access them while gparted is running, first do the operations, close gparted and then u will see them again.